# How to limit load of Array depending on switch position

Tags: ios, xcode, annotations, switch-statement, nsuserdefaults

I load my annotations from plist and loop categories

```
NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

for(path in dict){

NSString *theCategory;

theCategory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", path];
NSLog(@"%@", path);

NSArray *ann = [dict objectForKey:theCategory];


for(int i = 0; i < [ann count]; i++) {


    NSString *coordinates = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Coordinates"];

    double realLatitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
    double realLongitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

    MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
    theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;

    myAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(realLatitude,realLongitude);        
    myAnnotation.title = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
    myAnnotation.subtitle = [[ann objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Address"];
    myAnnotation.icon = [[ann objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Icon"];


    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
    [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];

}

}
```

Then I have an switch in my settings

```
- (IBAction)saveSwitch:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *defs1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defs1 setBool: blackSwitch.on forKey: @"blackKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

**I need to limit display of annotations from specific category by this switch. How it can be done, if I loop categories?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your first loop, do this:

```
for(NSString *category in dict){
    if ([category isEqualToString:@"Whatever"]) {
        //continue?
        NSArray *ann = [dict objectForKey:category];
        BOOL blackKeyStatus = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"blackKey"];

        if (blackKeyStatus) {
            //switch ON
            //act appropriatelyForOnValue
            //begin Loop 2 here?
        } else {
            //switch OFF
            //act appropriately
        }

    } else {
        //do something else?
    }
```

If you're needing to test for a specific condition, do whatever is necessary to identify if that condition is met.

Comment: I have 7 categories and 7 switches, I need to limit my categories by this switches

Comment: I changed my answer based on you discussing categories and having a string named "category"

Comment: It says that 'ann' is unused variable

Comment: I'm not writing your code for you, dude. You have to adapt this stuff to your project. I don't know what your conditions are, so that ann object is unused because you have to decide when to do your second for () loop

Comment: sorry, changed the above comment so it didn't look so dbag-ish

Comment: It goes through all annotations, is it possible to just disable whole category? I have about 2000 annotations and that is so slow

Comment: Yes, look at the if ([category isEqualToString:...]) line.  That may or may not be what you want, but you check each category for whatever condition you don't want to parse and you skip that one